# A11y error: Links do not have a discernible name

Tags: html, accessibility

I have an error :

> Links do not have a discernible name Link text (and alternate text for
>   images, when used as links) that is discernible, unique, and focusable
>   improves the navigation experience for screen reader users. Learn
>   more.

I tried to include an aria-label but it doesn't work. This makes an error:

```
<a href="https://...../demo/index.php/Products/Description/Apple-Cinema-27/products_id-1" c="Apple Cinema 27">
  <img src="images/products/130_61ajN-dgGxL._SL1000_.jpg"
       alt="Apple Cinema 27"
       title="Apple Cinema 27"
       width="130"
       height="130"
       class="media-object img-fluid">
</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm lost on the context of the error, I assume this is an a11y utility. If so, which one?

Comment: @stealththeninja: I'm guessing Lighthouse. The "Learn more" link points (or is supposed to point) to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/descriptive-link-text Nowhere does it suggest adding an aria-label though, so I'm skeptical as to whether they've read the document.

Comment: It does seem strange that the alt text isn't being considered here - maybe Lighthouse is erring on the side of caution and assuming that not all AT will see or announce an image's alt text.

Comment: The code example, as posted, is valid and WCAG compliant.  Something else is missing if you're getting this error.  An `<a>` does not need visible text or an `aria-label` if there is a nested `<img>` that has an `alt` attribute.  The 'alt' attribute becomes the "accessible name".

Answer (score 10):

Try use aria-label="...." - this is alternative text for image.

```html
<a
   href="https://...../demo/index.php/Products/Description/Apple-Cinema-27/products_id-1"
   data-c="Apple Cinema 27"
   aria-label="yourdescription">
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the alt attribute just needs a slight modification. The alt attribute should identify the destination or purpose of the link. Here is a very simplified example:

```
    <a href="contact.html">
        <img src="contact.png" alt="Return to the contact page">
    </a>
```

You may not therefore need an aria-label attribute.