# Why do my links not have a discernable name?

Tags: html, accessibility, lighthouse

I've read some of the other questions related to this issue but they didn't help me. I've tried adding `aria-labels` but that didn't help either. I still get, as failing elements, the links of the type `<a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>`.

Here is the HTML in question (just a basic browser checker that outputs some info in a table):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="An internship project. Holla at ya boy!">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#175506">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <script defer src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p>Check if your browser is relatively secure</p>
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>OS</td>
      <td id="os"></td>
      <td>Windows had several problems in the past with browser security. <a href="https://gizmodo.com/google-shames-microsoft-for-not-fixing-windows-10-brows-1792819255" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter">A Gizmodo article</a> and <a href="https://news.softpedia.com/news/google-discloses-windows-10-browser-vulnerability-that-microsoft-failed-to-patch-519844.shtml" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter2">a Softpedia article</a> have some things to say about it.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Browser</td>
      <td id="browser"></td>
      <td>The best way to make sure your browser is relatively secure is to <a href="https://updatemybrowser.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter3">keep it up to date</a>.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IP</td>
      <td id="ip"></td>
      <td>The IP can be an entry point into your system.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Browser timezone</td>
      <td id="timezoneBrowser"></td>
      <td rowspan="2">If the browser and IP timezones don't match, one can assume that you are using a VPN.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IP timezone</td>
      <td id="timezoneIP"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plugins</td>
      <td id="plugins"></td>
      <td>The more plugins you have, the bigger the attack area.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fonts</td>
      <td id="fonts"></td>
      <td>The more fonts you have, the chance that your browser has a unique configuration increases, alongside its entropy <a href="https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter4">(EFF whitepaper)</a>.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Monitor size</td>
      <td id="monitorSize"></td>
      <td rowspan="4">Useful for fingerprinting.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Browser size</td>
      <td id="browserSize"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This screen is a</td>
      <td id="touchscreen"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adblocking is</td>
      <td id="block_me"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Flash is</td>
      <td id="flash"></td>
      <td><a href="https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-53/product_id-6761/Adobe-Flash-Player.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter5">Flash is bad, mkay?</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Track" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter6">Do Not Track</a> is</td>
      <td id="dnt"></td>
      <td>From a security (not privacy) standpoint, as the number of third-party connections increases, so does the chance that one of them is malicious. Also, less connections equals less network usage, making things speedier.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Referrer</td>
      <td id="referrer"></td>
      <td>A referrer is the page from which you arrived at the current page. Now what if you arrived here from your bank's website and your bank included sensitive info in the URL? It's not that uncommon. <a href="https://blog.avatao.com/How-I-could-steal-your-photos-from-Google/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter7">Even Google has this problem</a> from time to time.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <p><strong>This is not the only information that your browser gives away!</strong> More ways to check your browser:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://browserleaks.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter8">browserleaks.com</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://panopticlick.eff.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter9">panopticlick.eff.org</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://dnsleaktest.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter10">dnsleaktest.com</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://ipleak.net" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter11">ipleak.net</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://ip-check.info/?lang=en" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter12">ip-check.info</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://browserspy.dk" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter13">browserspy.dk</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://amiunique.org/fp" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter14">amiunique.org</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://tenta.com/test" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Twitter111">tenta.com</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What is going on? Is this a Lighthouse issue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "name"? Not just the `name="..."` attribute?

Comment: I mean the link text. According to Lighthouse: "Link text (and alternate text for images, when used as links) that is discernible, unique, and focusable improves the navigation experience for screen reader users." Every `<a>` attribute, however, has discernible text.

Comment: I believe this is because the actual link text in your case isn't very specific.  "A Gizmodo article" would be more discernible should it be more specific to the link, like "Google Shames Microsoft for not fixing WIndows 10"

Comment: @Fraze I added so much text to each link that it's ridiculous. Still...

Comment: The same warning was mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53368300/6002174), 24 days ago.

Comment: Not really the same thing, since I don't have any `<img>` elements, but I nevertheless tried that fix (as mentioned in my question)...

Comment: @Fraze The link texts look sufficiently specific to me. @wombat Try replacing the domain-name-like link texts with the real site names and see if the issue persists; e.g. Panopticlick instead of `panopticlick.eff.org`. It is also possible that the `aria-label` overrides the link texts, and those attribute values look really bad.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I remove all the `aria-label` attributes and changed the domain-name-like link texts with the real site names. Same score.

Comment: That does not make any sense to me. Can that code be accessed somewhere over HTTP? I'd like to check it in a more realistic way.

Comment: I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mepsnoy0/).

Comment: Both the fiddle page and the code posted in the OP run clean through lighthouse (and aXe). (The fiddle page **does** have a "discernable text" error but it's on the fiddle page itself, outside of your example.) As long as there's text between the `<a></a>`, you're ok. If you have `aria-label`, you're ok. If there's no text but instead you have an `<img>` and the image has the `alt` attribute, then you're ok. The tools don't care what the text is, as long as there's text.  One item you didn't address (2nd comment) is **focusable**.  If you don't have an `href`, then the link is not focusable.

Answer (score 2):

The links in the code example have both a meaningful link text (although domain names should be replaced with site names) and `aria-label` attributes. As explained in [WCAG Technique ARIA8](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/aria/ARIA8), `aria-label` is really just for situations where the link text cannot (or does not) provide a meaningful description of the link target:

> The objective of this technique is to describe the purpose of a link using the aria-label attribute. The aria-label attribute provides a way to place a descriptive text label on an object, such as a link, when there are no elements visible on the page that describe the object. (...)

Also, the [Principle 2: ARIA Can Both Cloak and Enhance, Creating Both Power and Danger](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#no_aria_better_bad_aria) in the WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1 points out that ARIA sometimes overrides the original semantics or content, using `aria-label` as an example.

The link in submitted code example have `aria-label` values that read "Twitter3", "Twitter5", "Twitter4", etc., which I would expect screen readers to read *instead of* the link text, thereby creating an inaccessible experience. So in this case, the `aria-label` attributes should be removed.

As [Patrick Lauke](https://twitter.com/patrick_h_lauke/status/550065823118016512) and many other accessibility experts have pointed out:

> the first rule of ARIA club is...you don't use ARIA

With proper link text and without the `aria-label` attributes, the issue should disappear. (It did when I tested it over HTTP.) If Lighthouse still complains about it, you may need to empty your browser cache and/or clear the storage (see the checkbox above the "Run audits" button in Lighthouse). I cannot reproduce the issue once the link texts have been updated and the `aria-label` attributes removed.

---

Note: for the official formulation of "first rule of ARIA club", see the W3C's [Using ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1), which is a working draft at the time of writing:

> If you *can* use a native HTML element [[HTML51]](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/) or attribute with the semantics and behaviour you require **already built in**, instead of re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state or property to make it accessible, **then do so**.

Comment: FYI, the reference about the first rule of ARIA use is "officially" documented on the W3 page https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1.  It says if you can use native markup, then do so, then use ARIA if you have to.  Technically, it doesn't say not to use ARIA.  A nit-pick but possibly important for those new to accessibility.

Comment: @slugolicious Sure. I added a note about that.